# Detecting number repetition in R using regex

Tags: regex, r

Shouldn't this code work for repeating number detection in R?

```
> grep(pattern = "\\d{2}", x = 1223)
[1] 1
> grep(pattern = "\\d{3}", x = 1223)
[1] 1
```

If we have 988 we should get true and if 123 we should get false.

Sounds like it isn't.

```
> grep(pattern = "\\d{2}", x = "1223")
[1] 1
> grep(pattern = "\\d{2}", x = "13")
[1] 1
```

Comment: You have to have it as a string `"1223"` not an int `1223`

Comment: `\d{n}` matches an n length sequence of *any* digits. I think you want a backreference, although I'm not sure of what the syntax is in R.

Comment: I want to see if I have repeating number in the string or not.

Comment: Spitballing here, but `(\\d)\1{1,}` might work. This matches one digit, followed by one or many of whatever was matched inside the first parenthesis (i.e. the initial digit).

Comment: No it didn't, plus I don't know what it does `> grep(pattern = "(\\d)\1{1,}", x = "1223")
integer(0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use backreferences:

```
> grep(pattern = "(\\d)\\1", x = "1224")
[1] 1
> grep(pattern = "(\\d)\\1{1,}", x = "1224")
[1] 1
> grep(pattern = "(\\d)\\1", x = "1234")
integer(0)
```

---

EDIT: Seems like you need to figure how it works:  `(\\d)` creates a *capture group* for the `\\d`, which can be referred to using a backreference `\\1`.  For example, if you have numbers like `x2y` and you want to find those where `x` is the same as `y`, then:

```
> grep(pattern = "(\\d)2\\1", x = "121")
[1] 1
> grep(pattern = "(\\d)2\\1", x = "124")
integer(0)
```

<sub>I'd strongly recommend that you read a basic tutorial on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).</sub>

Comment: Somebody who has read the mind of Mona should say what really is being asked. Looks to me as though all of her x arguments should have matched the patterns offered.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat The examples in the question are vague; my answer is based on the question title `:)`

Comment: @MonaJalal That should be a separate question. If this answer satisfies the requirements you set out in this question (which seems to be the case), you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question explicitly says "using regex" in the title, but here is a non-regex method that could work, depending on what you want to do.

```
strings <- c("1223","1233","1234","113")

# detect consecutive repeat digits, or characters
(strings.rle <- lapply(strings, function(x)rle(unlist(strsplit(x,"")))))

[[1]]
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 1 2 1
  values : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"

[[2]]
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 1 1 2
  values : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"

[[3]]
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  values : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"

[[4]]
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 2 1
  values : chr [1:2] "1" "3"
```

Now you can work with `strings.rle` to do what you want

```
# which entries have consecutive repeat digits, or characters
strings[sapply(strings.rle, function(x) any(x$lengths > 1))]
[1] "1223" "1233" "113"
```

or

```
# which digits or characters are consecutively repeated?
lapply(strings.rle, function(x) x$values[which(x$lengths > 1)])
[[1]]
[1] "2"

[[2]]
[1] "3"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "1"
```